# Adafruit LCD + Keypad IOError: [Errno 5] RasPi 3

Tags: python, hardware, gpio, lcd, adafruit

So Ive successfully implemented Adafruit's 16x2 LCD + KeyPad and gotten it working on my Raspbian microSD. However I want to use it on my Volumio microSD, and Im having trouble getting it to function. I have followed the i2c configuration here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c, as well as all the necessary steps in the LCD + Pad's "Usage" section (here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16x2-character-lcd-plus-keypad-for-raspberry-pi/usage). A couple tweaks here and there and I was able to run the char_lcd_plate.py from Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/examples, but only through the Raspbian OS. When I try running the same example while in Volumio, I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "char_lcd_plate.py", line 9, in <module>
    lcd = LCD.Adafruit_CharLCDPlate()
  File "/home/volumio/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD/examples/Adafruit_CharLCD.py", line 432, in __init__
    self._mcp = MCP.MCP23017(address=address, busnum=busnum)
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 153, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 50, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/MCP230xx.py", line 133, in write_iodir
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_GPIO/I2C.py", line 127, in writeList
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/Adafruit_PureIO/smbus.py", line 274, in write_i2c_block_data
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

The most common solution I have come across has been bad connection/bad soldering, however the fact that it functions properly on my Raspbian OS makes me think that it is something else. I can provide pictures regardless if it is requested.

Also for what it is worth, before I arrived at this IOError, I was getting an `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/i2c-0'` I was able to fix this (if you can call it that) by following the "Enabling i2c-0" section here: (can't link because I dont have enough "reputation", but basically I added dtparam=i2c_vc=on to /boot/config.txt in addition to what Adafruit's i2c configuration page told me to add). This took care of my [Errno 2].

Comment: i2c driver is not complied i think there.

Comment: @Hackaholic How would I go about checking? would `lsmod  | grep i2c` work?

Comment: try this once http://hackaholic.info/raspberry-pi-lcd-mount/

Comment: `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` returns a periphery at 0x20 so I believe the driver is not the issue.